# How can i do performance testing of chat

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, bots, chat

I have 2 portals

- Staff portal (a web application)
- Member portal (a web application)

**How to establish a chat**

1. Send request from Member portal
2. Accept that request from Staff portal
3. Once the staff accept the request, they can start sending the messages

**REQUIREMENT**

1. I want to measure the response time of each message (How much time taken to reach message from Member portal to Staff portal?

**CHALLENGES**

1. How can i launch 2 applications (Member and Staff portal) and accept the request when 1000 members are sending request (I am using Silk performance tool/Jmeter, you can help me with any tool you know)
2. I can measure the time taken to send the message, but i couldn't measure the time when the message reach to staff.

Please let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 0):

For JMeter you can use the following approach:

1. Use 2 separate [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), one for "Member portal", another for "Staff portal"
2. When initiating the chat you can:

   - obtain the current timestamp using [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)
   - store it into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) (if you plan to use > 1 thread - add [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function as prefix or postfix for the property name)
3. Then in another thread group you can "wait" for the incoming message using [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/)

   - once message request arrives again use __time() function to get the current timestamp
   - get the previous timestamp from the first thread group using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)
4. Now you can calculate the delta between these 2 timestamps using [__longSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum)
5. Going forward you can save the value into the .jtl file using [Sample Variables property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables), [plot the values in the HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs), etc.

Comment: Thanks...I will try the above method...But I might face some issues on step3 that how can i know the message has reached to the concern portal. Since when i am sending message then an API is sending but on receiver side only incoming message is displaying there is no particular API for receiving message. Also, If i used selenium then i could use getText() function. Please help me out here